# Dropdowns and filters not applied with REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dropdown

I'm not able to display my menus (`_ids.name`) that match my filters from the 2 dropdowns (`MyNorm1,...MyNorm6`) and (`Classification1,...Classification6`). For example, when I click on my filters and select for example `MyNorm6` and `Classifications1` I want to see all the names of my menus that match these filters i.e `Pea Soup` , `Chicken tenders` and `Samosa` for this example.

Here an image to get the idea:[image]

```
export default function Filters({ onValidation, display }) {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
  const [submit, setSubmit] = useState();

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    const { name, checked } = e.target;
    setFilters((filters) => ({
      ...filters,
      [name]: checked
    }));
  };
...
  const NORMS = [
   ...
    { label: "MyNorm6", value: "norm6", checked: false }
  ];

  const CLASSIFICATIONS = [
   ...
    { label: "Classification5", value: "Classification5", checked: false }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      //Apply & Reset button not working...
      </div>
      <div className="text-md font-bold  rounded-md p-5 dark-shadow-sm leading-8 text-gray-500 flex flex-wrap gap-x-8 gap-y-4">
        Norms: <CustomDropdown options={NORMS} isMulti={true} />
      </div>
      ...      
      <div className="my-3 h-6 text-xl  uppercase font-bold leading-8 text-gray-500">
        Matched Menus
      </div>
       //FILTERS NOT WORKING ...
            ...
                {NORMS.map((name) => (
                  <td key={name}>
                    <label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        checked={filters[name]}
                        onChange={changeHandler}
                        name={name}
                        className="w-8 h-3"
                      />
                      {name}
                    </label>
                  </td>
                ))}
              </td>
            </tr>
            {data
              .filter((item) => {
                const filterEntries = Object.entries(filters)
                  .filter(([, value]) => Boolean(value))
                  .map(([key]) => key);

                if (filterEntries.length) {
                  if (filters.item) {
                    return item.norms.some((n) =>
                      filterEntries.includes(n.norms)
                    );
                  }
                  if (filters.item) {
                    return item.classification.some((n) =>
                      filterEntries.includes(n.classification)
                    );
                  }
                }
                return true;
              })
              .map((item) => (
                <tr key={item.id}>
                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
          </tbody>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here the [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-dream-e5xbsm)

Comment: Can you post some of the relevant code in a minimal example in your question?

Comment: Yes I 've now edited my question

Comment: Sorry, is it okay now? I've commented all the filtering part, so you can see my dropdowns are displayed but the commented code is not working.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what the issue actually is? What isn't working?

Comment: @DrewReese I've edited my question and update my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-northcutt-g88bzb?) (let's check `Filters2.jsx`)

Comment: @DrewReese I've opened a new [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176101/unable-to-display-my-fetch-data-in-my-table-cells)

Comment: BTW, there seems to be a missing import or error with the latest sandbox code.

Comment: Oh true! it's fixed now

Comment: @DrewReese is it working now ([code](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-dream-e5xbsm))

Comment: @DrewReese I've opened [issue1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72236655/react-how-do-i-add-a-cross-x-on-top-of-all-pages-of-a-multi-form-to-quit-it-and), [issue2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72233256/react-i-dont-see-the-event-traceability-when-i-select-or-check-an-option)